# How to Get Android TableRow background color?

Tags: android, colors, background, tablerow

I've created a spreadsheet in Android to display the results of a data search using TableRow. The TableRows are dynamically created so there can be up to 30 rows displayed at a time.

I'm trying to toggle the background color of a row when the user touches the row, and can easily change the background color with an android:onClick event. However once the row is clicked and the color changes I cannot toggle the color back when another android:onClick event is initiated.

So how do I determine the color state of the TableRow so I can construct the proper control flow and toggle the color appropriately? There are plenty of examples of how to set the background color, but nothing helpful in GETTING the background color.

Thanks

Comment: i would suggest you set default color to all the table rows so that you can reset to that default color when the user clicks some other tablerow.

Comment: The user must be able to select multiple rows, so I must first determine the color state of the row clicked. There is a default color assigned, but I don't know how to toggle back to it.

Comment: getBackground() returns a Drawable. What do you do with that?

Comment: Try somthing like this: `Drawable drawable = getBackground();
if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable)
{
   ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) drawable;
   int color = colorDrawable.getColor();
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// save old view style
Drawable defaultViewStyle = view.getBackground();

// set new style
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_view_style);

// return default view style
view.setBackgroundDrawable(defaultViewStyle);
```

But I think it's not the right way. It is best to override all of the possible conditions for the view:

```
// res drawable my_table_row_style:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_table_row_style_selected"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_table_row_style_selected"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/my_table_row_style_selected"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/my_table_row_style_default"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
int MyPosition=100000;
...
...
onclick()
{
 if(MyPosition==100000)
 {
 //first time selection
  MyPosition=a//a=any int position
 //change bg of selected row
 }
 else
 {
//now u r selecting second or N th time
//so first set previous bg of MyPosition
//and clear MyPosition
//Now set bg of current bg nd set MyPosition
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the color you set by setTag() and retrive it by getTag().

```
void OnClick(View v)
{
  Integer color = v.getTag();
  if (null == color) // not clicked yet
  {
     color = COLOR_NOT_TOGLED;
  }
  if (COLOR_NOT_TOGLED == color)
  {
     color = COLOR_TOGLED;
  }
  else
  {
     color = COLOR_NOT_TOGLED;
  }
  v.setBackGround(color);
  v.setTag(color); // save
}
```

**UPDATE**
Ok, let's fix it))

```
void OnClick(View v)
{
    Object o = v.getTag();
    Integer color = (null == o) ? COLOR_NOT_TOGLED : (Integer) o;
    if (COLOR_NOT_TOGLED == color) {
        color = COLOR_TOGLED;
    } else {
        color = COLOR_NOT_TOGLED;
    }
    v.setBackgroundColor(color);
    v.setTag(color); // save
}
```

Comment: Presumably, you need to set tags as the table is created, and then keep track of all the tags. I just want to identify the color, check to see if it's changed.

Comment: @user1168400. If you see my pseudocode, you will find that i proceed the case if tag wasn't set yet (if tag is null). So you don't need to "initialize" tags of every row on table creation. If tag of clicked row is null i suppose that this row is in "not togled" state and we need to set backgrownd color to COLOR_TOGLED. Anyway, my answer is just the trick to solve your problem. If i were doing this functionality, I wold create a something like list or sparsearray to save the states of each row.

Comment: Integer color = v.getTag(); is not compatible as v.getTag() is an Object, not integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look in source code of `setBackgroundColor()` you see how it works:

```
TableRow tr = (TableRow)v;
Drawable bg = tr.getBackground();
int oldColor = ((ColorDrawable) bg.mutate()).getColor();
```